# Python multiprocessing crashes when calling f2py functions

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing, f2py

I am using python2.7 (mac os homebrew) to run multiprocessing and the program crashes and spitted out errors as follows. It seems like one of the f2py-wrapped functions relies on lapack and the system doesn't like to fork that. Thoughts?

```
   __TEXT                 000000010c502000-000000010c504000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Application Specific Information:
*** multi-threaded process forked *** crashed on child side of fork pre-exec

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0   libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fffdbaa6749 _dispatch_queue_push
+ 171 1   libLAPACK.dylib                   0x00007fffc34fc2c4 DGETRF + 1139 2   _flapack.so                    0x000000010d6bb703 f2py_rout__flapack_dgetrf + 323 3   org.python.python                0x000000010c514921 PyObject_Call + 99
```

Comment: Is this happening inside an ipython session (instead of just plain python)? If you are using ipython, try using `no_proxy` variable:

```$ env no_proxy='*' ipython```

[https://blog.yimingliu.com/2015/07/22/python-multiprocessing-code-crashes-on-os-x-under-ipython/]